# Condensing MySQL Query By Eliminating Redundancy

Tags: mysql

My current MySQL query looks like

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(time1, time2)), YEAR(time2), MONTH(time2), DAY(time2), HOUR(time2)     
FROM rr
WHERE time2 IS NOT NULL     
GROUP BY      
YEAR(time2),      
MONTH(time2,       
DAY(time2),       
HOUR(time2);
```

What I'm looking to do is to now order the group by results by date based on the new group by results. Is there a way to do this without having to specify

```
ORDER BY
  YEAR(time2)
  ...
  HOUR(time2)
```

all over again?

Additionally, is there a way to return a DateTime field instead of having to reconstruct on with the `YEAR(time2), MONTH(time2)... HOUR(time2)` columns? It seems like there is a fair amount of redundancy that I can reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
order by min(time2)
```

In MySQL, you could also do:

```
order by time2
```

But I recommend using the aggregation function.

As for the second part of your question, you could do:

```
select date(date_format(time2, '%Y:%m:%d %h:00:00'))
```

Comment: *Is there a reason for the anonymous downvote?* I could only guess:  jealousy . But your answer is perfectly fine :D